# delete text with 'strikethrough' font in docx document using python

Tags: python, xml, text, fonts, docx

I need to delete text with 'strikethrough' font (L̶i̶k̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶.) in .docx documents. I have tried to use python-docx package. However, some of the text are in textbox in the word document and python-docx cannot detect strikethrough font in textbox. Is there any other python package/method that can do this job?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: have you asked the python-docx community how to do this, first? (like posting on https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues ?)